# Equinumerousity and equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading the book of Mathematical Analysis Volume 1  written by V.A.Zorich and I would like to clarify some moments from that book.

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary sets.  A subset $R\subset X\times Y$ is called relation on $X\times Y$. If $(x,y)\in R$ we will denote it as $xRy$.
The relation on $X\times X$ is called equivalence relation if the following three properties are true:

1. Reflexivity. For any $x\in X$ $\Rightarrow$ $xRx$.
2. Symmetry. If $x_1Rx_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_2Rx_1$.
3. Transitivity. If $x_1Rx_2$ and $x_2Rx_3$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_1Rx_3$.

In the case of equivalence relation we will replace the notation $xRy$ by $x\sim y$ and the above three properties can be written as:

1. Reflexivity. For any $x\in X$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\sim x$.
2. Symmetry. If $x_1\sim x_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_2\sim x_1$.
3. Transitivity. If $x_1\sim x_2$ and $x_2\sim x_3$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_1\sim x_3$.

**Definition:** We say that the set $A$ is equinumerous to the set $B$ iff there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

It is clear the this relation is equivalence relation and hence we will denote it as $A\sim B$ instead of $ARB$.

*Question:* Yes I am almost agree with this but you see that in the definition of equivalence relation we have the "big" set $X$ and $R\subset X\times X$. What is $X$
in the definition of equinumerous sets? We cannot take $X$ to be the set of all sets, right? Because this notion is contradictory by Russel's paradox.

Can anyone explain my question please in simple language? I am not an expert in mathematical logic so please try to give simple answer.

Comment: It is simply $A \times B$: $\sim \ \subseteq A \times B$

Comment: Example: $\mathbb N$ and $\text {Even} = \{ n \mid n \in \mathbb N \land n \text { is even} \}$ are equinumerous: $\sim = \{ (n,2n) \mid n \in \mathbb N \} \subseteq \mathbb N \times \text {Even}$

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, I did not get your answer at all. Could you be more specific? Maybe my question was unclear?

Comment: In ZFC, you need to choose an arbitrary "universe" $X$ for everything to be valid. In NBG, you can take $X$ as the *class* of all sets (but then don't speak of "equivalence relation", as that would claim the relational class to be a set, speak just of an equivalence). There are set theories in which a universal set exists, in such I guess things would work if $X$ is taken as the set of all sets.

Comment: You can use also $A \cup B$ We have: $A,B \subseteq A \cup B$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, what do you mean by "universe" $X$ for everything to be valid? BTW thanks that you commented my question!

Comment: In ZFC we cannot speak of the collection of all sets, so for everything to make sense we need to pick a set for the equivalence relation to live in (for, by definition, an equivalence relation is a set). That set then plays the rôle of the "universe", we ignore everything not in that set. That's not very satisfactory, though, so it's better to work in NBG (where we have the class of all sets) or in a meta theory of ZFC where we can speak of the collection of all sets. But then we don't have an *equivalence relation* (because such is by definition a set), instead we say just "equivalence".

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes indeed in ZFC we cannot speak about "the set of all sets". As you said then we need to pick a set where the equivalence relation lives. Then this set plays a role of "universe". You said that we ignore everything which is not in this set. But then how to define equinumerousity(cardinality) for the sets which is not in this universe? This bothers me a lot. So in this case it turns out that cardinality is not defined for each set but for some particular class of sets living in our "universe".

Comment: Perhaps Zorich used naive set theory including the set of all sets, ignoring contradictions and paradoxes. (I suppose an exotic set theory including the set of all sets while avoiding Russell's paradox would have been explicitly mentioned.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks a lot for your answer! But I don't think so since he mentioned before this discussion Russell's paradox and emphasized that the notion "the set of all sets" is contradictory. It bothers me a bit :(